# How to set div's id with jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jsp, expander

I receive list of feed items from Servlets

```
<c:forEach items="${feedItemsList}" var="feedItem">
    <table class="contentItem">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="block">
                    <a id="" href="javascript:showFeedItem(${feedItem.id});"><c:out
                            value="${feedItem.title}" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="feedItemExpander" id="${feedItem.id}">...My
                    info...</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to expand and collapse div with id=${feedItem.id}.
Clicking on

```
<a id="" href="javascript:showFeedItem(${feedItem.id});"><c:out
                            value="${feedItem.title}" /></a>
```

I pass `${feedItem.id}` to jQuery function. Then showing div with `id=${feedItem.id}`.
My function:

```
function showFeedItem(feedItemId) {
            $('.feedItemExpander').each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).attr("id") == feedItemId) {
                $(this).show(200);
            }
        });
    }
```

How to collapse it by second click on the same link?

Comment: I do not see any Java in this post.

Comment: I think you need to change the TAG from Java to Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide it by clicking on the same link, do a check to see if the element is visible and then either hide or show it based on that:

```
function showFeedItem(feedItemId) {
    $('.feedItemExpander').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == feedItemId) {
            if (!$(this).is(':visible')) $(this).show(200);
            else $(this).hide(200);
        }
    });
}
```